# Is it possible to create an array of Bitmap in android

Tags: android

I wanna create an bitmap array. Is it possible?
If yes, which is the way to declare the Bitmap array. and how to initialize it?

Thank you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use an Arraylist :

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
bitmapArray.add(myBitMap); // Add a bitmap
bitmapArray.get(0); // Get first bitmap
```

or simply an Array of bitmap like :

```
Bitmap[] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[];
```

Nevertheless be careful with the size of your image. You will probably have some trouble if you try to store lot of big image.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible,
If bitmap1 and bitmap2 are objects of bitmap. I can assign them to an array as follows.

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.a_thumb);//assign your bitmap;
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.anotherimage);//assign your bitmap;
        Bitmap[] arrayOfBitmap = {bitmap1, bitmap2};
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Just like any array, for example:

```
Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[] { BitmapFactory.decodeResource(...) /* etc. */ }
```

There is nothing special in the fact that the objects in array are `Bitmap`s.

Comment: Just be careful doing this since it can very quickly lead to out of memory problems if you load large/too many bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can make bitmap aaray in android like this,

```
byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
            buf.read(bMapArray);
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
            image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Use this android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) for details.

Use [this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/2/) too

Answer (score 0):

All the above/below solutions are possible but a common case is actually using a HashMap as it is the case with Image Downloaders and async bitmap loaders.

A Bitmap is an object as may others (String arrays, Integer arrays etc...) so you might modify those methods you find also for storing bitmap arrays.